# List data from two table in tableView

Tags: c++, qt, sqlite, qtgui

How can I list data from two table in tableView?

Database (Example) Sqlite:

```
tb_sales
  tb_product
  tb_value
  tb_customer_id (Customer Id "tb_customer")

tb_customer
  tb_customer_id (id primary key)
  tb_name
  tb_state
```

With `QSqlRelationalTableModel` fetch only the client's name. Also need the `state`.

```
model= new QSqlRelationalTableModel(this); 
model->setTable("tb_sales");
model->setRelation(2, QSqlRelation("tb_customer", "tb_customer_id", "tb_name"));
model->select();
ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`QSqlRelationalTableModel` only allows you to include one column from the secondary table. You can use `QSqlQueryModel` to have a query in which you join the two tables :

```
QSqlQueryModel *model = new QSqlQueryModel;
model->setQuery("SELECT tb_sales.* , tb_customer.tb_name, tb_customer.tb_state FROM tb_sales LEFT JOIN tb_customer ON tb_sales.tb_customer_id = tb_customer.tb_customer_id");

ui->tableView->setModel(model);
```